# $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}} = \mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}} \oplus \mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, self-learning, free-modules

I am solving the following question from Aluffi chapter 0. I constructed the following counter example.

I know by intuition that the following there exists an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}} = \mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}} \oplus \mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$. I am trying to find explicit isomorphism between these two.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the mapping
\begin{align}
\mathbb Z^{\oplus \mathbb N} \oplus \mathbb Z^{\oplus \mathbb N} & \longrightarrow \mathbb Z^{\oplus \mathbb N} \\ ((a_1,a_2,\dots),(b_1,b_2,\dots)) & \longmapsto (a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,\dots)
\end{align}